# Freezing rotating platform when parent object rotates in Unity

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2D platformer game in which I want to have a rotating platform like the one in this image.

http://thegamedesignforum.com/features/WEBSMW/RDSMW4/d13.png

The first idea I had for this would be to have one parent object and one platform as child of that object and a script that will rotate the parent object. However, that will end up having platform's z axis rotating as well, so I need something that will make platform rotate around the parent object, but make platform's rotation remain still.

One solution I found to this was the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour
{
     public Vector3 rotator;
     public Transform platform;

     Quaternion offset;

     void Start ()
     {
           offset = transform.rotation;
     }

     void Update ()
     {
           platform.rotation = offset;
           transform.Rotate(rotator * Time.deltaTime);
     }
}
```

This works, but there is one problem: the platform ([as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAMEu.png)) rotates around the parent object, but is also tilted a bit. I don't want it to have any tilt.

Another interesting thing that is happening is the higher rotation speed I set, the more the platform tilts. Can you tell me why this is happening and maybe give a better solution to having a rotating platform?

Comment: I would set the rotation of the platform **after** rotating the parent

Comment: That never occured to me, it works now. Thank you.